# Dynamic Uri and Routing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have an `Admin_Controller` extends to my `Backend_Controller` in Codeigniter 2. And also have a `Site_Controller` extends to my `Frontend_Controller` that runs all the Front End.

What I need is to get uri_string in `Site_Controller` `index` method. I will decide what to display based on retrieved string.

How can I achieve this? I am not really fun to write all possible routes to `routes.php`. What I need is simply go to anywhere match naturally. If does not match the natural way, go to `Site_Controller` `index` method instead of 404 page.

Comment: Provide more code to help us help you.

Comment: try `_remap()` method in your controller.if no method is defined all request will land on this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codeigniter `_remap` method can be used to achieve this behaviour. Here is the [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping).

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'some_method')
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```